# VPN и провайдер

Tags: сеть, vpn, openvpn, провайдер

Что видит провайдер при использование VPN (openvpn) c AES-256.

Видит какие сайты посещались и конкретно ссылки(которые открывались)?

Логи какие у него?

Comment: А VPN поддерживает все протоколы или только http, куда смотрят dns через vpn или к провайдеру, как обычно ?

Comment: И "провайдер" - это который со стороны клиента или со стороны vpn сервера ?

Comment: провайдеру vpn обычно все видно, как обычному видно не трафик без vpn. то есть, http - без проблем, https - если есть сертификат (или его подменили). Большинство vpn продают данные о траффике пользователей - это их бизнес. Ну и компетентным органам по запросу могут отдать. В целом, vpn защищает только если это свой vpn.

Answer (score 1):

Если dns сервер провайдера не используется и маршрут до него пролегает через vpn. В этом случае провайдер знает что вы подключенны к впн и на каком хостинге его подключили.

Разорвав впн в некоторый момент днс может переключиться на провайдерский и тогда можно случайно подсмотреть куда вы полезли.

При утечке данных сертификатов, логинов и паролей сервер впн можно подменить если не используется прверка серверного сертификата.