# Socks5 и интернет-провайдер

Tags: сеть, socks5, провайдер

Что видит интернет-провайдер при использовании socks5?

Интернет-провайдер видит какие сайты посещались, и конкретно ссылки(которые открывались) при использовании socks5?

Какие логи при использовании socks5?

Фиксируется ли факт использования socks5 у интернет-провайдера?

Comment: продолжение исследования https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1233211/vpn-%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%b4%d0%b5%d1%80 ?